# VS 2019 - Schema Compare - "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted" when TrustServerCertificate=True

Tags: sql-server-2016, visual-studio

I'm trying to do a schema compare in VS 2019 with **Active Directory Password Authentication**. The account I'm using works in SSMS, but fails in VS with the following error, even when TrustedServerCertificate is True.

> The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted

Here is a screenshot of what I'm entering and one with the **TrustedServerCertificate** property set to **true**.

[image]

[image]

Anyone know what could be the issue? Is there something that needs to be enabled on the server?

Comment: Having the same problem. Ever find a solution?

Comment: I just hit this.  My workaround was to right click VS and select `run as` to run it under the account that had access to the DB.  Another workaround would be to create a SQL login instead of using AD.  Not sure why the impersonation itself doesn't work; I'd guess something extra needs to be configured (maybe some Kerberos setting?), but haven't delved / the workaround was a sufficient quick fix for my needs.